# zf2 DB insert using custom query is not working

Tags: insert, zend-framework2, adaptor

We are developing a website using ZF2. We alreday started the project. We installed ZF2 skelton application and integrated the album module. Everything seems working. Now we are trying to integrate multiple zend forms in a module. Forms eveyrything we made [ by modifying the albulm module elements) I am able to insert/update/delete etc data in to the default table that set on the module.php file [this is for form 1].
I have another form which requires to insert/delete/update to another table, I created new form class, Table class (on model) etc. When I tried to insert the data in to Db using custom query format, it throws error:

```
File:
/home/catholic/public_html/propertydosth/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Sql/Insert.php:298
Message:
The key adapter was not found in this objects column list.
```

It seems adaptor value is not getting something..

My Code for insert query:

```
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $sql         = new Sql($adapter);
    $insert      = $sql->insert('dad_cms');
    $newData     = array(
        'category_id' => $admin->category_id,
        'cms_title'  => $admin->cms_title,
        'cmd_desc' => $admin->cmd_desc,
        'seo_keywords'  => $admin->seo_keywords,
        'seo_titles' => $admin->seo_titles
    );
    $insert->values($newData);
    $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
    $results = $insert->adapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

I am getting correct query value when I echoed $selectString . 
Any one please suggest what is wrong in my code to get it done.

Comment: Please format your Question so someone will actually be able to read this ;) See [the Formatting Help-Site](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Yes. I was just formatting.  Since long time I am trying for this.Also Sam your blog helped us a lot to configure zend basic settings. Hope you can help on this crisis?

Comment: I don't know too much about `Zend\Db` but the error message suggest that your last line is wrong `$insert->adapter->...` you're trying to access a column like this. See [the third Example of the Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-sql-quickstart). It should just be `$adapter->query(..)` i assume

Comment: Thank u very much Sam. This issue took lot of time. Your answer saved me now. Really appreciated your timely reply and correct answer.I am expecting your help in future also . :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally Sam helped me on this issue:
So correct Answer become [this will be helpful somebody having similar issue. Even I spent lot of time to debug the same]:

```
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
$sql         = new Sql($adapter);
$insert      = $sql->insert('dad_cms');
$newData     = array(
    'category_id' => $admin->category_id,
    'cms_title'  => $admin->cms_title,
    'cmd_desc' => $admin->cmd_desc,
    'seo_keywords'  => $admin->seo_keywords,
    'seo_titles' => $admin->seo_titles
);
$insert->values($newData);
$selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($insert);
$results = $adapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```